# Backup mysql table

Tags: mysql

What's the better way to do a back up of a sql table in the linux server

I do this way :

```
Create table backuptablecustomer like customer

insert into backuptablecustomer select * from customer
```

But is there another way?

Comment: Backup a table... how/where?  Do you want it backed up to a file?  You can use `mysqldump` for that.  Or do you want it backed up some other way?

Comment: yes in a file how I can use mysqldump?

Comment: See: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/ Note: `mysqldump` has to be run from the command line.

Comment: You can also try using `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`.  `SELECT * FROM customer INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/backups/customer.sql'`

Answer (score 3):

The mysqldump utility will produce a text file with SQL commands that can then be used to restore the tables and data.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html.

E.g.

```
mysqldump -u user -p db_name customer > customer.sql
```

Comment: Or better yet: `mysqldump -u user -p db_name customer > customer.sql`.

Comment: Im trying in local but it doesn't work it says you have an error in your Sql syntax

Comment: @sarikaya: `mysqldump` *isn't* a SQL query.  You don't run it inside MySQL.  It's a command that you need to run on the server's command-line directly.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: that's what I did. I tried on wamp in mySql console

Comment: @sarikaya: No, you don't run it in the MySQL console.  `mysqldump` (or rather `mysqldump.exe` is a program).  You need to open a command prompt and run the command.  Since you mentioned WAMP, that means it's Windows.  Open the start menu, type `cmd`, open the command prompt, then run the command (you'll probably need to `cd` to the WAMP install directory first - something like `cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\bin`).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to back up the table using an SQL query, then you can try using `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`.

```
SELECT * FROM customer INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/backups/customer.sql';
```

Comment: Oh nice didn't know this one. Really usefull thanks. Thats the easiest one

Comment: You're welcome.  `mysqldump` is better if you are trying to make backups (like in a script/CRON or something), this is if you want it to be an actual SQL query.

Comment: ok thanks, one more question. Where the sql backup files are? In which folder?

Comment: @sarikaya: That's up to you.  Wherever you want to put them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks thats the command I did and it works :

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysqldump -u user -p db_name customer > customer.sql
```